# Pivoting table sql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have this table:

```
|............id.............|............a............. |.............b............|
|...........123qwe....      |...........0.............  |.............13...........|
```

and I need to pivot it like this:

```
|.........id................|........indicator....      |.............value........ |
|...........123qwe....      |...........a.............  |.............0.............|
|...........123qwe....      |...........b.............  |.............13........... |
```

There are more thatn 100 columns with indicators as headers (a,b,c,d,e,f,...) so a sort of loop would be needed.

Comment: This is actually an unpivot.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161888/like-unpivot-in-sql  It's pretty easy to setup a formula in Excel to build the select from unionall then fill down and copy paste. `="SELECT ID, '" & A1 & "' as Indicator, " &A1&" as Value FROM thisTable UNION ALL "` where column A contains all the field names  (Assuming no special characters in field names.)  and field names can come from a sys table.

Comment: To get all the field names for your table... `SELECT column_name FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE     table_name = 'ThisTable'`  then adjust to remove those not needed to be pivoted.

Comment: like @xQbert says iam pretty sure there can be found a example on this website [stackoverflow search "mysql dynamic unpivot"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+dynamic+unpivot) ... This one [Dynamic Query in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805562/dynamic-query-in-mysql) looks good i also marked this post as duplication.. HIs answer can have flaw tho `GROUP_CONCAT` has a max length off 1024 you need to set it larger with `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;` for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this：

```
SELECT id, 'a' AS indicator, a AS value
FROM test
UNION
SELECT id, 'b' AS indicator, b AS value
FROM test;
```

and if you want loop, you'd better write it in the program...

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT id, 'a', SUM(a)
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY id
 UNION 
 SELECT id, 'b', SUM(b)
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY id
 UNION
 ...
```

As usual, the *right* answer is to normalize you schema.

Comment: The problem with this is that it needs to be done 100 times and the column names have 30 random characters each

Comment: @Gordon: Where do you think the duplicate rows arise from, given that the second attribute is unique and hard coded in each SELECT?

Comment: @Vlad: if you want an efficient solution, try option 2.

Comment: @symcbean; I don't think it's about the duplication in this case.  I think it's a method to force the engine to avoid executing the distinct done by a union and thus gain performance.  The things we do to eek out faster results ;P

Comment: Though now you make me ask... why is a sum and group by needed if there are no duplicates?  I'm probably missing something simple though, I do that alot.